# Regex grab numbers after dollar sign

Tags: android, regex

I have dynamic strings that sometimes will have a price in them and sometimes not. Its for craigslist so there is really no set format there can be commas, dashes, etc. Here are some examples of a typical string:

> Xbox 360 (black) Elite Console 120GB (Mason City Illinois ) $200
>
> $200 2013 North Trail Camper (RT 202. Manchester, Maine) $224/mo.
>
> Snowmobile Bike trailers (Winthrop / Augusta) $40 Monthly
>
> "Great Xmas Gift" XBox 360 Guitar Hero (Springfied) $80

I am trying to split up the string into title, location, and price. I can grab the location with:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\(([^]*)\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(title);
```

Having trouble figuring out how to separate the title and price out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"\\$(\\d+)"` or `"\\$(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"` is a start, and then grab `matcher.group(1)` for the number, but expect a fair amount of debugging to get this kind of thing right. People are too unpredictable :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab number after `$` use: `\$[0-9]+` regex.

Comment: a little more explanation would help

Comment: @Cyzanfar, \$ matches the character $ literally
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9

Answer (score 1):

To grab number after `$` use `\$(\d+)` regex.

## [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nfWQlT/1)

Note the capturing parentheses, the desired value will be accessible via `m.group(1)`.

Double escape backslashes in Java code, too.

See snippet below:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(title);
String output = "";
if (m.find()) {
    output = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering how to avoid extracting `$123` from `$0000$123`, I'd suggest using `"\\B\\$(\\d+)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use:

```
 \$[-0-9.,]+[-0-9.,a-zA-Z]*\b
```

It will take quite a few non-numbers, but it will also glob up stuff like negative values, `$1,000`, `$1mil` and so on. The `\b` at the end will ensure it globs up as much as possible before a space or new line or something.

Comment: I tried putting this into http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but couldn't seem to get it to work.